# How to apply a linebreak inside a sentence

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment, text-manipulation

I want to write down a claim (i.e. a sentence), which consists of three important elements.

The first part (the left hand side of the claim) is supposed to be a very short statement, which I would like to write in two lines, then I would like to use an arrow like `\to` and then there's supposed to be another short sentence, again with a linebreak (i.e. two lines).

It's somehow supposed to look like this

statement one --------> statement two

and each statement is supposed to have a line break inside but the sentence, as a whole, is supposed to be horizontally aligned as sketched.

How can I manage to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set each sentence inside a `minipage` of prespecified width, and insert an extensible right arrow via `\xrightarrow`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
  Left text that should span
  multiple lines.
\end{minipage}\hfill
$\xrightarrow{\hspace{.15\linewidth}}$\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
  Right text that should span
  multiple lines.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks so much @Werner. This was exactly what i was looking for!